# eclipse can't start in ubuntu (not open jdk)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, java-8

[Java version and eclipse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9zzw.png)

[The folder for usr/java/jdk1.8.0_241 and usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X29VO.png)

Sadly the installation seems to have several problems

When I open Eclipse I get the following error :

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to un Eclipse. No java Virtual machine was found after searching the following locations :
>   usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/default.ee
>   usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/java
>   usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/libjvm.so

Further information :

`~/bashrc` wasn't changed

[/etc/environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goIeQ.png)

[eclipse.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b21Sm.png)

I downloaded jdk-8u241-linux-x64

Comment: Copy&paste all text shown in your screenshots to the question **as text**. Which Linux distribution and version do you use? Where did you download the JDK from and how did you install it? You wrote "the installation seems to have several problems". Did the installation show any errors? Please [edit] your question to add information, don't answer in comments.

Comment: In the `eclipse.ini` you have `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241` instead of `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java`. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM